# Socket.io to listen the emit message when another user opens up another website on same server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

As another user who has to open the same website again, I want to know what was the last emitted message from the user so that any particular action can be implemented.

> **Example:** On the same server I have two websites hoisted and I want to know weather *website 1 is still open or not when I open 2nd
>   website*.

Vice Versa has been implemented via ***socket as website 2 gets opened it emits message which is received by website 1 but when I open website 1 and therein website 2 is not opened yet, hence after some time if I open website 2 I wants to know if website 1 is still opened or not.***

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
  // ...
});
```

to try and have one website ping another, and if the ping does not come back, then there is no other website.

Also with websockets you get a client object in the backend with all there info, in the front end you can add a key to the client object inside the on("connect") and in the backend check all clients for key 1 which corresponds to website one, and key 2 which can correspond to website 2. Let me know if you need more help!